# AC analysis of a Bias Tee

Tags: amplifier, rf, bias, fet, s-parameters

I am designing a bias tee here and wondered whether it actually works or not? Hence I conducted an AC analysis instead of S-parameters (after verifying that s parameters are okay). The bias tee has been designed for 900 MHz assuming 50 ohm impedances. So the circuit is as below:

[image]

And the resulting currents are as below:

[image]

[image]

Now, my questions are:

1. Why DC current is frequency dependent, it should have been a constant of about \$i=\frac{1 V}{50 \ \Omega}=0.02\ \mathrm A \$?
2. Why the output (RFDC) current is smaller than the RF (input) current ? It should have been the addition of both currents, just shifted up by 0.2 A?

Answer (score 3):

> Why DC current is frequency dependent,

Because at low frequecies the inductor (L1) doesn't do a good job of blocking signals from the AC source

> it should have been a constant of about \$i=\frac{1 V}{50 \ \Omega}=0.02\ \mathrm A \$?

The DC source (SRC4) doesn't have any effect on the AC simulation. AC simulations only calculate the response to the AC sources in the model.

> Why the output (RFDC) current is smaller than the RF (input) current ?

Some of the current is going through the DC arm, because the inductor is an imperfect blocker at the frequencies being simulated.